# Likert scale question as a dependent variable

Tags: regression, survey, ordinal-data, likert

I have a questionnaire with many items. The researcher defined several items to be dependent variables of interest for analysis. Some of them are represented by a single likert scale question with a , i.e, categorical variable with 5 levels:

5 - strong disagreement
4 - disagreement 
3 - medium agreement
2 - agreement
1 - strong agreement

Unfortunately, with no other questions, using Cronbach's alpha and then averaging the scores is not plausible and I will need to analyze a single question.

Since the dependent variable is ordinal, I could do an ordinal regression. More than that, I could recode the values so groups 1-2 are together and so are 4-5. However group 3 is "medium" and I do not know where to put it, so I remain with an ordinal regression.

Ordinal regression is not intuitive to people, and I wish to avoid using. Is there another way to handle this analysis (assume various independent variables, categorical or continuous). I was thinking maybe some transformation and then assuming that the latent variable behind the likert scale variable is continuous, but this is a shot in the dark.

How should I analyze this ?

Example data is attached in the table below:

[image]